# Python: AttributeError in Multiple Choice Quiz

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm relatively new to Python and have recently been working through a tutorial that builds a basic multiple choice quiz. Everything appears to be functional except for one section which is coming up as a AttributeError.

Here's the code:

```
class question_Class:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer


question_prompts = [
    "What colour are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
    "What colour are bananas?\n(a) Teal\n(b) Magenta\n(c) Yellow\n\n"
]

question_class_objects = [
    question_Class(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    question_Class(question_prompts[1], "c"),
]


def run_test(question_class_objects):
    score = 0
    for question in question_class_objects:
        answer = input(question_Class.prompt)
        if answer == question_Class.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(question_class_objects)) + "correct")



run_test(question_class_objects)
```

The errors are from the question_Class.prompt() and question_Class.answer: portions of the run_test function.(AttributeError: type object 'question_Class' has no attribute 'prompt').

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In your `run_test()`, I think you mean to do `question.prompt` and `question.answer` instead of `question_Class.prompt` and `question_Class.answer`. After all, the _class_ doesn't have any attributes - its _instances_ do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
for question in question_class_objects:
    answer = input(question_Class.prompt)
    if answer == question_Class.answer:
        score += 1
```

by

```
for question in question_class_objects:
    answer = input(question.prompt)
    if answer == question.answer:
        score += 1
```

Since you iterate on your list `question_class_objects` with the variable `question`, you need to use your variable to access your prompt and your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much - your explanation made total sense!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Because the class has multiple instances (the two questions) you have to give the class variable an instance to work with. So you could simply do “question_Class.prompt(question)” same thing goes for question_Class.answer.